# Search a file in PHP for a string and return the next line

Tags: php, file

I have a file I am reading in with `php`:

```
$lines = file("input.txt");
```

I need to search `$lines` for the string `--><--` then return the very next full line. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: `grep -A 1 "--><--" input.txt` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through the array `$lines` and increment the key by 1 to get the next line.

```
$lines = file("input.txt");

$return = array();
foreach($lines as $key => $line) {
    if(false !== strpos($line,'--><--')) {
        // check if there is another line in the file
        if(isset($lines[($key+1)])) {
            // add the line to array
            $return[] = $lines[($key+1)];
        }
    }
}
print_r($return);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if you were matching a Windows or a Unix file (hence the `\r?`), but you can do it with Regular Expressions much more cleanly. You can capture it like this:

```
$lines = file("input.txt");
preg_match('!(--><--\r?\n)([^\r\n]+)\r?\n!s',$lines,$matches);
$myLine = $matches[2];
echo $myLine;
```